# Keep Alexa from responding when I'm talking in my sleep

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

If I'm in a private meeting at my home, I don't really want Alexa piping up with her idle chatter if I or someone else accidentally says the wake word.

Equally, if I'm talking in my sleep (which I do a lot of), I don't want to accidentally wake up Alexa and disrupt my sleep.

Is there a way to silence the Amazon Echo temporarily so it doesn't respond to accidental wake ups when I want it to remain quiet?

Comment: [this link here](https://www.howtogeek.com/237397/how-to-stop-your-amazon-echo-from-listening-in/) would be of help to you!

Comment: Pick a really complicated wake word?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny If you've found a relevant link, feel free to post that as an answer and quote the relevant source. The help center has some information on [referencing other sources in answers](http://iot.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), so that you can convert your comment to a full answer and add some extra information there. Using comments to post links to answers [isn't recommended](http://iot.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) because the question doesn't get marked as answered even if the link is helpful.

Comment: Lolx - a new First World Problem is born ... sleep shopping @-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can press the [**microphone on/off button**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201602230) on the top of your device to disable the microphone before you go to sleep. Here's what it looks like for the Echo Dot:

[image: Amazon Echo Dot]

<sup>Source: [FASTILY](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Amazon_Echo_1_2017-02-23.jpg?uselang=en-gb) of Wikimedia Commons, CC-BY-SA 4.0</sup>

After pressing the microphone off button, your device will look more like this:

[image: Amazon Echo Dot (microphone disabled)]

<sup>Source: [Hedwig Storch](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1024_amazon_Echo_Dot-2808.jpg?uselang=en-gb) of Wikimedia Commons, CC-BY-SA 4.0</sup>

Notice the illuminated microphone off button and the red ring. While the ring is red, your device will **not** be listening at all, until you press the microphone on/off button again. The Amazon Echo will look largely the same, except it's significantly taller. The icon on the microphone on/off button is the same as in the pictures above.

Unfortunately, [you can't turn off the Echo's microphone by voice](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/861/can-i-ask-alexa-to-turn-off-its-microphone/862#862)—the button must be *physically pressed*. Also, you can't turn the microphone back on by voice, because—well—the microphone is off, and can't listen to you, because you told it not to!

Comment: Half true. You could kill the echos power by voice if you plug it into a Wi-Fi plug ;) obviously you won't be able to reactivate it via voice.

Comment: Or, you could use a script to modify the wifi settings which really upsets alexa